# JSON array with VB.Net

Tags: json, xml, vb.net, rest, json.net

I'd like to create this JSON content with VB.NET and can get the WriteStartArray() implemented properly. The content needs to become the payload for a REST API call.

The token structure is a bit challenging for me to create. I'm used to XML and have to adjust to the new representation for the API's I'm calling.

It would be great to have a visual mapping of the Newtonsoft code to a simple and advanced JSON document. I my case I'm building a prototype for an integration. Trying to keep the final solutions as simple s possible for other enthusiasts to have an easy entry with JSON in VB.NET.

While utilizing https://dotnetfiddle.net/ I learn faster with a working example.

Sample data:

```
{
      "cilist": [
            {
                  "id": "bppmwsserver_6",
                  "className": "BMC_ComputerSystem",
                  "attributeMap": {
                        "HomeCell": "pncell_bppmwsserver",
                        "PNReadAcl": "[]",
                        "WriteSecurity": "[Full Access]",
                        "PNWriteAcl": "[]",
                        "DATABASE_event_max_sev": "OK",
                        "PriorityWatchdog": "NO",
                        "UsingOrganization": "",
                        "OwnerContact": "",
                        "Domain": "calbro.com",
                        "status": "OK",
                        "maintenance_mode": "NO",
                        "schedule_status": "IN",
                        "HostName": "bppmwsserver",
                        "manual_status": "NONE",
                        "root_causes": "[]",
                        "computed_priority": "PRIORITY_5",
                        "DeviceID": "1",
                        "impacting_open_event_max_sev": "OK",
                        "InstanceId": "",
                        "USER_TRANSACTIONS_event_max_sev": "OK",
                        "ImpactCostPerSecOut": "0.000000e+000",
                        "APPLICATION_event_max_sev": "OK",
                        "SYSTEM_event_max_sev": "OK",
                        "Company": "",
                        "OwnerName": "",
                        "Description": "Test CI",
                        "sub_status": "NONE",
                        "UsingOrganizationId": "-1",
                        "any_event_max_sev": "OK",
                        "Priority": "PRIORITY_5",
                        "Name": "bppmwsserver.calbro.com",
                        "publish_env_id": "",
                        "mc_udid": "bppmwsserver_6",
                        "ReadSecurity": "[Full Access]",
                        "PrimaryCapability": "Server"
                  }
            }
      ]
}
```

Sample Code:

```
Public Shared Function DefineJsonServerCI() As String
    Dim JsonCI As New JTokenWriter()
    Try

        JsonCI.WriteStartObject()
        JsonCI.WritePropertyName("cilist")
        JsonCI.WriteStartArray()
        JsonCI.WritePropertyName("id")
        JsonCI.WriteValue("CI ID")
        JsonCI.WritePropertyName("className")
        JsonCI.WriteValue("BMC_ComputerSystem")
        JsonCI.WriteEndArray()
        JsonCI.WriteEndObject()



    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(" Exception:{0};Create JSON CI;{1}", ex.Message, ex.Source)
    End Try
    Return JsonCI
End Function
```

Any suggestions?
Thx, O.

Comment: Thank you for the info Brian. I don't want to end up with many models. Each API call has it's own structure and some of it might be dynamic. Would you happen to have some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing you might find it easier to create model classes for your JSON and serialize those rather than manually coding JSON using a `JsonWriter`.

You can generate model classes by copying a sample of your desired JSON to the clipboard (the more filled out the better), and then in Visual Studio using the `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes` function.  Be aware that this function does not generate array properties correctly, so you'll need to manually correct those.  You can change the class names to be whatever you want.  The property names need to match what you want in the JSON output, unless you decorate them with a `<JsonProperty>` attribute specifying the alternate name to use in the JSON.

With your sample JSON I generated these model classes:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property cilist As List(Of Cilist)
End Class

Public Class Cilist
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property className As String
    Public Property attributeMap As Attributemap
End Class

Public Class Attributemap
    Public Property HomeCell As String
    Public Property PNReadAcl As String
    Public Property WriteSecurity As String
    Public Property PNWriteAcl As String
    Public Property DATABASE_event_max_sev As String
    Public Property PriorityWatchdog As String
    Public Property UsingOrganization As String
    Public Property OwnerContact As String
    Public Property Domain As String
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property maintenance_mode As String
    Public Property schedule_status As String
    Public Property HostName As String
    Public Property manual_status As String
    Public Property root_causes As String
    Public Property computed_priority As String
    Public Property DeviceID As String
    Public Property impacting_open_event_max_sev As String
    Public Property InstanceId As String
    Public Property USER_TRANSACTIONS_event_max_sev As String
    Public Property ImpactCostPerSecOut As String
    Public Property APPLICATION_event_max_sev As String
    Public Property SYSTEM_event_max_sev As String
    Public Property Company As String
    Public Property OwnerName As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property sub_status As String
    Public Property UsingOrganizationId As String
    Public Property any_event_max_sev As String
    Public Property Priority As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property publish_env_id As String
    Public Property mc_udid As String
    Public Property ReadSecurity As String
    Public Property PrimaryCapability As String
End Class
```

Note that the `cilist` property in the `Rootobject` class was originally generated incorrectly like this:

```
    Public Property cilist() As Cilist
```

And I manually corrected it to this:

```
    Public Property cilist As List(Of Cilist)
```

To create the JSON from there, it's just a matter of populating the models and serializing them:

```
Dim obj As New Rootobject With
{
    .cilist = New List(Of Cilist) From
    {
        New Cilist With
        {
            .id = "bppmwsserver_6",
            .className = "BMC_ComputerSystem",
            .attributeMap = New Attributemap With
            {
                .HomeCell = "pncell_bppmwsserver",
                .PNReadAcl = "[]",
                .WriteSecurity = "[Full Access]",
                .PNWriteAcl = "[]",
                .DATABASE_event_max_sev = "OK",
                .PriorityWatchdog = "NO",
                .UsingOrganization = "",
                .OwnerContact = "",
                .Domain = "calbro.com",
                .status = "OK",
                .maintenance_mode = "NO",
                .schedule_status = "IN",
                .HostName = "bppmwsserver",
                .manual_status = "NONE",
                .root_causes = "[]",
                .computed_priority = "PRIORITY_5",
                .DeviceID = "1",
                .impacting_open_event_max_sev = "OK",
                .InstanceId = "",
                .USER_TRANSACTIONS_event_max_sev = "OK",
                .ImpactCostPerSecOut = "0.000000e+000",
                .APPLICATION_event_max_sev = "OK",
                .SYSTEM_event_max_sev = "OK",
                .Company = "",
                .OwnerName = "",
                .Description = "Test CI",
                .sub_status = "NONE",
                .UsingOrganizationId = "-1",
                .any_event_max_sev = "OK",
                .Priority = "PRIORITY_5",
                .Name = "bppmwsserver.calbro.com",
                .publish_env_id = "",
                .mc_udid = "bppmwsserver_6",
                .ReadSecurity = "[Full Access]",
                .PrimaryCapability = "Server"
            }
        }
    }
}

Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented)
```

Here is a working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9xA8Hf

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is that after creating the first array, you have to start another object (as indicated by the `{` character). So, if you edit your code like this:

```
Public Function DefineJsonServerCI() As String
    Dim JsonCI As New JTokenWriter()
    Try
        JsonCI.WriteStartObject()
        JsonCI.WritePropertyName("cilist")
        JsonCI.WriteStartArray()
        JsonCI.WriteStartObject()
        JsonCI.WritePropertyName("id")
        JsonCI.WriteValue("bppmwsserver_6")
        JsonCI.WritePropertyName("className")
        JsonCI.WriteValue("BMC_ComputerSystem")
        JsonCI.WritePropertyName("attributeMap")
        JsonCI.WriteStartObject()
        JsonCI.WritePropertyName("HomeCell")
        JsonCI.WriteValue("pncell_bppmwsserver")
        JsonCI.WriteEndObject()
        JsonCI.WriteEndObject()
        JsonCI.WriteEndArray()
        JsonCI.WriteEndObject()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(" Exception:{0};Create JSON CI;{1}", ex.Message, ex.Source)
    End Try
    Return JsonCI.Token.ToString 
End Function
```

You will get the following JSON object. You just have to add the rest properties of your attributeMap object.

```
{
  "cilist": [
    {
      "id": "bppmwsserver_6",
      "className": "BMC_ComputerSystem",
      "attributeMap": {
        "HomeCell": "pncell_bppmwsserver"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've created a .NET fiddle. See the code in action at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0roThW

Comment: So, I guess that this code snippet solved you problem. You may want to accept the answer, if it helped you.